# Exchange one letter and I can be silenced

Tags: riddle, word, lateral-thinking, language

Tired of short riddles yet?

> *I claim me, myself, and I.
>
>   I can be found in stone, and I can find stone.
>
>   I can burst, causing irreparable damage.
>
>   I am an abundance.*
>
> *I am?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you

> **vein**?

If you are, then:

I claim me, myself, and I.

> because you are "vain"

I can be found in stone, and I can find stone.

> if a miner finds a vein of ore, he'll try to follow it to find the mother lode

I can burst, causing irreparable damage.

> ruptured blood vessels are somewhat dangerous

I am an abundance.

> of minerals

Title:

> Veil of silence, maybe?

Tired of short riddles yet?

> Not at all, as long as they clearly identify a unique answer.

Comment: Quite creative! Some of your interpretations are correct. rot13(lbh zragvba n xrljbeq va lbhe frpbaq thrff. Lbhe sbhegu thrff gvrf vagb gung nf jryy, ohg gur sbhegu yvar ersref gb fbzrguvat ryfr.).

Comment: One part I'll mention as well- rot13(Lbh zragvba obgu "inva" naq "irva". Va guvf pnfr, gur nafjre vf dhvgr fvzvyne, nygubhtu vg vf fcryyrq gur fnzr ab znggre ubj vg vf hfrq va gur evqqyr. Vg vf nyfb sbhe yrggref, nf lbhe nafjre vf.)

Comment: @iiiidk if you want to add clues to the question, or just give some extra hints, please do it in the question, where everyone can see them. I am almost certain I got the intended answer from the extra clues here, but I don't want to change my answer to yours, because *mine* fits the abundance clue much better.

Comment: After a nap, the more that I read yours, the closer it seems to mine, so I'm going to accept it since you've actually mentioned the word I was looking for.

Comment: @iiiidk then what is your intended answer?

Comment: Instead of "vein", it was "mine", which Bass mentions in his explanation, and in his comment down here. @malioboro

Answer (score 0):

`Tired of short riddles yet?`

> Nope $\;\stackrel{\bullet\,\bullet}{\smile}$

---

Could you be a

> **Ton**?

`I claim me, myself, and I`

> The word **ton** *claims* the sound **one**, namely, a single identity (me, myself, and I: **one**self).

`I can be found in stone, and I can find stone.`

> Ton can be found in s**ton**e, and quite a lot of rocks and stones (or boulders, in particular) can weigh at least a **ton**.

`I can burst, causing irreparable damage.`

> Anything that weighs at least a ton, and then breaks, is bound to cause irreparable **damage**. (Who's seen a falling piano? And they weigh at most *half* a ton.)

`I am an abundance.`

> A ton is a very **large** and **heavy** unit of weight (i.e. $2000$ pounds).

`I am?`

> A **ton**?

---

**Title:**

`Exchange one letter and I can be silenced.`

> Exchange only **one** letter (a clue to solving the first line) and **I** can be silenced. The letter $\verb|I|$ has a similar sound to the letter $\verb|y|$, and if you replace $\verb|n|$ with $\verb|y|$, you get **toy**, which makes a different sound than the letter $\verb|y|$ itself (a.k.a. **silenced**) and does not weigh a ton. 
>  
>  Also, if you solve the short riddle, you can strike it out in the line,
>  `Tired of short riddles yet?` 
>  to find the replacement letter; i.e., 
>  "Tired of <s>short riddles</s> yet" $\to$ "**T**ired **o**f **y**et?" $\to$ **Toy**.